Color changes with polarization
Plane polarized light is passed through a second polarizer whose polarizing direction is, say, at $80^o$ to the polarizing direction of the first polarizer. How does one experimentally measure the frequency of light before and after the second polarizer?

Usually one measures wavelength. You can measure the wavelength with a diffraction grating.
